# How to change the partition size without re-install the OS?

Tags: operating-systems, partitioning

My system partition is running up. But I can't afford to re-install the OS. I heard that it's possible to change the partition size without re-install OS. Any tools for that? My OS is Windows Server 2008 R2.

Thanks.

Comment: Not a programming question in any way. Better on SuperUser.com, but I believe that is has bee asked and answered there more than once already.

Comment: Yes, please move it there. I am totally ok with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Partition Magic Server 2008, which [supports Windows Server 2008](http://www.partition-magic-server.com/server.html).

Answer (score 0):

I just tried [EASEUS Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/). It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

[GPartEd](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) has worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. But I need to work on windows platform, reluctantly...

Comment: I booted from the live CD and changed the sizes of my NTFS partitions with GPartEd and then rebooted into Windows w/o any problems. Please follow GPartEd's documentation on details for NTFS resizing.